# Can Maven a plugin use itself as a plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins

I've written a Maven plugin which we're using as part of our release process - as well as the usual release basically does some extra admin. I'd like to use this plugin for releasing the plugin itself but I'm not sure this is possible.

If I include the plugin in its own POM, using ${version} as the version number then I can't release because before deploying the release build it can't find the release build in the Nexus repo. If I use an earlier version, I get a clash (I don't think Maven likes two versions of the same project at once) and I'm not having any luck using a 'provided' scope as the plugin tag doesn't support this.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or should I resign myself to having a different release procedure for the plugin itself?

Thanks,
-Dave

Comment: Simply a cycle which does not work. Apart from that using a plugin mean having the plugin released first to have a immutable version of that and afterwards use this plugin.

Comment: Ok, it will have to have its own special release procedure. Thanks for the info.